# How to prevent yarn install from running twice in Makefile?

Tags: gnu-make

I have this in my `Makefile`:

```
node_modules: yarn.lock
    yarn install --production=false
    touch node_modules

yarn.lock: package.json
    yarn install --production=false
    touch yarn.lock
```

Basically, if the `node_modules` directory is missing (or someone has tampered with it by adding/removing files), or `yarn.lock` has been updated, then it should run `yarn install` to rebuild/integrity check the `node_modules` dir.

However, if `yarn.lock` is missing, it can be rebuilt from `package.json`, or if `package.json` is updated, then it should install and rebuild the lock file.

The problem is when both `node_modules` *and* `yarn.lock` are missing, then the same commands run twice.

How can I prevent this?

---

I can *nearly* get it to work by wrapping the directives in a conditional:

```
ifneq ("$(wildcard yarn.lock)","")
node_modules: yarn.lock
    @yarn install --production=false
    touch node_modules

yarn.lock: package.json
    touch yarn.lock
else # yarn.lock does not exist
node_modules: yarn.lock
    touch node_modules

yarn.lock: package.json
    @yarn install --production=false
endif
```

Now if you `touch package.json` and then `make node_modules` and `yarn.lock` exists, then it'll subsequently `touch yarn.lock` which will cause `node_modules` to rebuild, just like I want.

However, if you `touch package.json` and then `make yarn.lock`, technically it should attempt a `yarn install` but it won't because I removed the command from this directive:

```
yarn.lock: package.json
    touch yarn.lock
```

To prevent it from running twice in the former scenario.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To a first approximation, consider the approach illustrated here:

**Makefile (1)**

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: yarn.lock

yarn.lock: node_modules package.json
    $(MAKE clean)
    yarn install --production=false

node_modules:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -fr node_modules yarn.lock
```

This will never run `yarn install` redundantly, and it's a *somewhat* more
robust solution than you're considering. I'll explain.

The one *source* item in the problem is the `package.json`. It is the sole
logical prerequisite of everything else and is not itself to be built.

The `yarn.lock` is a build-artefact whose production signifies that that
`yarn install` has been done successfully with respect to the snapshot
of `package.json` that existed when it was done. `yarn install` will
subsequently consider that the installation is up-to-date as long as `yarn.lock`
exists and has contents that "agree" with `package.json` by criteria
that are algorithmically embodied in `yarn install`.

So, viewed simplistically, the mission of this build is just to make `yarn.lock`
up-to-date with respect to `package.json`:

```
yarn.lock: package.json
    yarn install --production=false
```

But it's actually more complicated. `yarn.lock` is the build target but
it isn't the *only* build-artefact and it isn't even *one of* the artefacts of
primary value. Those, of course, are whatever artefacts will populate
`node-modules` as a result of running `yarn install`.

So the primary build-artefacts appear as *side effects* of this build,
while the actual target, `yarn.lock` matters to us only as a *token* that
the primary artefacts, whatever they may be, have been made up-to-date
with the `package.json`.

And it is a frail token. Agencies can mess with the contents of
`node_modules` - adding files that shouldn't be there, deleting or
modifying ones that should - and `yarn install` won't do anything to
rectify it as long as *it* considers `yarn.lock` up-to-date with `package.json`,
by its own criteria.

You adverted to that fragility in explaining the suggested recipe:

```
node_modules: yarn.lock
    yarn install --production=false
    touch node_modules
```

> if the node_modules directory is missing (or someone has tampered with it by 
>   adding/removing files), or yarn.lock has been updated, then it should run yarn
>   install to rebuild/integrity check the node_modules dir.

But *that* rule is the wrong way round to be triggered by such tampering. The
tampering - if you're lucky - will update the modification time of `node_modules`.
But that will make it *younger*, not older, than `yarn.lock`, and won't fire
the recipe. The recipe is only good for the case in which `node_modules` does not exist.

That weakness is mitigated by the recipe:

```
yarn.lock: node_modules package.json
    $(MAKE) clean
    yarn install --production=false
```

If `yarn.lock` doesn't exist, or is out-of-date w.r.t to *either* `node_modules`
or `package_json`, we'll remake all the build-artefacts from scratch.

That's better, but brings with it a boot-strap problem, when neither of the
artefacts `yarn.lock` or `node_modules` exists but `node_modules` - which is to
be populated as a *by product* of making `yarn.lock` - is also a *perquisite* of `yarn.lock`.

It's a trivial problem however. The prerequisite for `yarn.lock` is the mere *existence*
of `node_modules` and it is satisfiable prior to making `yarn.lock`, and the
*contents* of `node_modules`, up-to-date - by just adding the recipe:

```
node_modules:
    mkdir -p $@
```

With this, if `node_modules` ever doesn't exist, it will be created as
a prerequisite of `yarn.lock`, making it newer than `yarn.lock`, and requiring
`yarn.lock` and the primary build-artefacts to be made.

**But...**

This solution expresses the dependency relations essentially right and - as
a consequence - shows how `yarn install` never needs to be run redundantly. And
it corrects the wrong-way-round bug in your tamper-detection logic.

But is still falls short of *strong* tamper-detection.

The tamper-detection mechanism we've got is: *Something happens in the* `node_modules`
*directory that makes its modification date later than that of* `yarn.lock`. That
will detect some tampering, but not all tampering.

As a filesystem object, a directory is modified - and its modification time updated
- if and only if an immediate child object is added, removed, or renamed. So
the tamper-detection mechanism is blind to all events inside any *subdirectory* of
`node_modules` and to any modification of an existing file or subdirectory of
`node_modules` except renaming it. That leaves ample scope for messing up
the `node_modules`.

In that light, you might decide to:-

**Stick**

*Flimsy tamper-detection is better than none.  I don't want to use any
more expensive than this.*

But you probably wouldn't. More likely alternatives:

**Fold**

*Tamper-detection this flimsy is no better than none, so I'll fall back to:*

```
yarn.lock: package.json
    yarn install --production=false
```

*I'll regard improper tampering as out-of-scope for my build. If it happens, something will break,
I'll notice it,* `make clean` *and try again.*

**Up the ante**

*I want strong tamper-detection.*

Strong tamper-detection makes rather heavier lifting - but not *much* heavier.
You need to force a clean `yarn install`, or not, depending on the outcome of an 
old-versus-new comparison between complete manifests of the contents of `node_modules` - 
manifests informative enough that any material difference will show up.

A manifest detailing the pathname and modification time of every file in
`node_modules` is the best candidate. This manifest will contain the information that `make`
would need to know, and would get from the file system, if the elusive primary artefacts
of this build could be spelled out to it, and a change in that information relative to
its last recorded state is a reliable trigger to remake everything. Thus:

**Makefile (2)**

```
RM := rm -fr
MANIFEST_DIR := .manifest
LAST_MANIFEST := $(MANIFEST_DIR)/node_modules.last
NEW_MANIFEST := $(MANIFEST_DIR)/node_modules.peek
GEN_MANIFEST := find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \;

$(shell mkdir -p $(MANIFEST_DIR) node_modules)
$(if $(wildcard $(LAST_MANIFEST)),,$(shell touch $(LAST_MANIFEST)))
$(shell $(GEN_MANIFEST) > $(NEW_MANIFEST))
$(shell cmp -s $(LAST_MANIFEST) $(NEW_MANIFEST) || touch node_modules)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(LAST_MANIFEST)

yarn.lock: node_modules package.json
    $(RM) yarn.lock node_modules
    yarn install --production=false

$(LAST_MANIFEST): yarn.lock
    $(GEN_MANIFEST) > $@

clean:
    $(RM) yarn.lock node_modules $(MANIFEST_DIR)
```

This develops **Makefile (1)** mainly with the unconditionally executed apparatus
at the top, which:-

- Ensures (as before) we start with a `node_modules` directory, even if empty.
- Ensures we start with a hidden directory (`.manifest`) for working in
  and for persisting the latest manifest of `node_modules`. (Analogous to
  the hidden `.deps` directory classically used for persisting autodependency files
  in C/C++ makes).
- Ensures we start with a persisted manifest, even if empty.
- Generates a new, true, manifest snapshot with: `find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \;`,
  which writes `<filename> <modification_time>` for each item under `node_modules`. 
  This snapshot is true of `node_modules` *as it is*, but not necessarily true
  of `node_modules` as it *should be*. (Should it follow symlinks? - `find -L ...`?
  No. Because `make` wouldn't follow symlinks for targets or prerequisites).
- Compares the new, true, snapshot with the persisted manifest and, if
  there is any difference, then touches `node_modules`.

This amounts to a build preamble that will update the modification
time of `node_modules`, or not, by a *strong* tamper-detecting test. Then
the build is much as before except that its target is no longer 
`yarn.lock`, but a new persisted manifest, `$(LAST_MANIFEST)`, that is always an
immediate post-`yarn-install` snapshot and accordingly dependent on
`yarn.lock`.

**A workout for Makefile (2)**

For a [lab-rat `package.json`](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample/blob/master/package.json)
I'll use:

```
{
  "name": "node-js-sample",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "Mark Pundsack",
  "contributors": [
    "Zeke Sikelianos <zeke@sikelianos.com> (http://zeke.sikelianos.com)"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**Make from scratch**

```
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.17s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Change nothing and remake**

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

**Touch `node_modules` only**

```
$ touch node_modules/
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.01s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Touch `package.json` only**

```
$ touch package.json 
imk@imk-ThinkPad-T420:~/develop/so/make_prob$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.22s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Touch `node_modules` and `package.json`**

```
$ touch package.json node_modules/
imk@imk-ThinkPad-T420:~/develop/so/make_prob$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.05s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Touch `yarn.lock`**

```
$ touch yarn.lock 
$ make
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Delete `yarn.lock`**

```
$ rm yarn.lock 
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.17s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Change a dependency in `package.json`**

```
$ sed -i 's/4\.13\.3/4.15.3/' package.json
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.03s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Undo the change**

```
$ sed -i 's/4\.15\.3/4.15.3/' package.json
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 2.35s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Touch an existing file in a subdirectory of `node_modules`**

```
$ ls node_modules/vary/
HISTORY.md  index.js  LICENSE  package.json  README.md
$ touch node_modules/vary/README.md 
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.02s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Add a file to a subdirectory of `node_modules`**

```
$ touch node_modules/vary/interloper
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.20s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

**Remove a file from a subdirectory of `node_modules`**

```
$ rm node_modules/vary/README.md 
$ make
rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules
yarn install --production=false
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.16s.
find node_modules/ -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \; > .manifest/node_modules.last
```

Comment: Wow! Very thorough. Thank you. I'm awarding you the points for that, but I need to play around with this a bit. Generally, `yarn.lock` should never be deleted. It's there to make sure you always get the same version of the packages. However, once in awhile I will manually delete it to force my packages to upgrade, or it might not exist for a new project, or if its not version controlled - in such scenarios I'd want to rebuild it, but otherwise leave it alone. How come "Make from scratch" starts with `rm -fr yarn.lock node_modules` if those don't exist yet?

Comment: There's also the issue an issue with "Makefile (1)" in that touching either package.json or node_modules will cause "make" to always run `yarn install` because `yarn install` won't touch `yarn.lock` if nothing needs to be done, making it perpetually out of date. However, if do touch yarn.lock, it will force an unnecessarily rebuild, but at least there will be "Nothing to be done" after that.

Comment: Thank you :) "How come Make from scratch etc... ?" In the bootstrap case we've ensured that `node_modules` exists (empty) and that the
very first old-v-new manifest comparison is arranged to report
a difference. That kicks off the stock rebuild, as we want. The stock
rebuild must remove `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` to ensure
`yarn install` regenerates both of them validly, and testing for
`yarn.lock`'s existence before `rm`-ing it is just more longwinded
than `rm -f`-ing it.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226605/65387), I think this is robust enough for my needs:

```
BIN := node_modules/.bin
SRC_FILES := $(shell find src -name '*.js')
DIST_FILES := $(patsubst src/%,dist/%,$(SRC_FILES))
DIST_DIRS := $(sort $(dir $(DIST_FILES)))

# these are not files
.PHONY: all clean nuke

# disable default suffixes
.SUFFIXES:

all: $(DIST_FILES)

dist/%.js: src/%.js yarn.lock .babelrc | $(DIST_DIRS)
    $(BIN)/babel $< -o $@

$(DIST_DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

yarn.lock: node_modules package.json
    @yarn install --production=false --check-files
    @touch -mr $(shell ls -Atd $? | head -1) $@

node_modules:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -rf node_modules dist

nuke: clean
    rm -rf yarn.lock
```

I added

```
@touch -mr $(shell ls -Atd $? | head -1) $@
```

Which updates the modification time of `yarn.lock` to the newer of `node_modules` or `package.json`. This is necessary for when those are touched but don't result in a lockfile change -- `yarn install` won't update the file which will cause `yarn.lock` to be perpetually out of date.

`--check-files` will force `yarn install` to actually reinstall any missing packages inside `node_modules/`, but it won't do a deep search. So if tamper some files inside of a package (rather than just deleting the whole package), this sort of change won't be caught.

The babel stuff is just an example of how I'm using this. It will recompile only the source files that have changed. Now I just have to run `make` in a freshly cloned project and it will bring everything up to date with one command.

Comment: Impressed with the answer! I guess bounties work! ;)